# how to optimize mysql's full text search to match strings like 'C++'

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

we use mysql's full-text search IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE, but the search does not match on terms like 'c++'. How can we optimize mysql to match correctly in a full text search and not to remove special characters? Characters like comma , should of course still be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you can declare defines that make your code simple to read, for example:

```
#define INSERT_INTO "INSERT INTO "
#define DELETE "DELETE "
#define VALUES "VALUES ( "
#define AND " AND "
#define JOIN "JOIN "
#define EQUAL "= "
#define LIKE " LIKE "
#define ORDER_BY "ORDER BY "
#define LIMIT "LIMIT "
#define SELECT "SELECT "
#define ALL "* "
#define FROM "FROM "
#define END_STATEMENT ";"
#define WHERE "WHERE "
#define SELECT_TRUE_FROM "SELECT 1 FROM "
```